# Anyway to create a jquery mobile checkbox effect in bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jquery-mobile, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am switching over to bootstrap from Jquery Mobile. What I really like about jQuery mobile is how their radio and checkboxes are styled on mobile devices. Is there anyway where I can have create a similar style on Bootstrap?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It will require some extra css on your part, but this is pretty close to what you're asking for.

http://jsbin.com/wexadi/2/edit?html,css,js,output